# Is 'import MyClass.MyClass' is equal to 'from MyClass import MyClass ' in python

Tags: python, import

If both ,

ModuleName is : `MyClass.py`

and

Class inside is :

```
class MyClass :
    ...
```

Comment: When you tried them, what did you learn?

Answer (score 2):

No, they're not the same. The first won't even work; an ordinary `import` statement imports *modules only*. The second will put `MyClass.MyClass` in your scope as `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

The `import <x>` only allows you to import modules -- you can't do `import <module>.<Class>`. You can only import a specific class using the `from <x> import <y>` form.